# ApplicationContext - Need clarification

Tags: spring

I am new to springs and have the following queries on ApplicationContext.

1.What does it mean to declare two instances of classPathXmlApplicationContext on a single beans.xml file?

2.How is a beanPostProcessor programmatically associated with a single ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.What does it mean to declare two instances of classPathXmlApplicationContext on a single beans.xml file?

This would result in two different Spring application context unaware of each other. If there are any beans that are defined as singleton, each application context will now have its own instances of singleton beans, which means two bean instances one for each application context.

> 2.How is a beanPostProcessor programmatically associated with a single ApplicationContext?

To register a BeanPostProcessor you can add that to the spring configuration(xml/annotation) as a normal bean and spring will detect that automatically during the container startup and will invoke its callback methods during bean creation.

If you want to do this programatically, you can use [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) and [addBeanPostProcessor method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html#addBeanPostProcessor-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor-)